# Why does XSLT change context unexpectedly?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I apply templates with variable in select attribute which contains part of a tree. From that I call another apply templates with following-sibling:: construction, but it applies to all tree. For example:

```
<a>
    <b id="1" ol="1" />
    <b id="2" ol="0" />
    <b id="3" ol="0" />
    <b id="4" ol="1" />
    <b id="5" ol="0" />
    <b id="6" ol="0" />
    <b id="7" ol="1" />
    <b id="8" ol="0" />
    <b id="9" ol="0" />
    <b id="10" ol="1" />
    <b id="11" ol="0" />
    <b id="12" ol="0" />
    <b id="13" ol="1" />
    <b id="14" ol="0" />
    <b id="15" ol="0" />
    <b id="16" ol="1" />
</a>

...
<xsl:variable name="part" select="b[@ol = 1] />
<xsl:apply-templates mode="top" select="$part[position() mod 3 = 1]" />
...
<xsl:template mode="top" match="*">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-template mode="inner" select=".|following-sibling::b[not(position() > 2)]" />
    </tr>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="inner" match="*">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></p>
<xsl:template>
```

What I expect is

```
<tr><p>1</p><p>4</p><p>7</p></tr>
<tr><p>10</p><p>13</p><p>16</p></tr>
```

What I have got

```
<tr><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p></tr>
<tr><p>10</p><p>11</p><p>12</p></tr>
```

So why did template "top" change context to complete tree instead of `$part` while applying following-sibling? And how to get expected variant?

Comment: Actually I need the answer not as much as I need correct code to get wanted structure described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath selects nodes in an input tree, it does never change that input tree. So selecting some nodes does not in any way change the structure and relations in the tree, the sibling or children or ancestors remain the same. If you want to manipulate a tree use XSLT or XQuery. As you already use XSLT, with XSLT 1.0 you would need to write templates to create a result tree fragment with the new structure, then after applying an extension function like `exsl:node-set` you can process the intermediate tree. With XSLT 2.0 you don't need the extension function but you need to construct an intermediate tree.

To achieve the output you want you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:variable name="part" select="b[@ol = 1]" />
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="top" select="$part[position() mod 3 = 1]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="top" match="*">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="inner" select=".|following-sibling::b[@ol = 1][not(position() > 2)]" />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="inner" match="*">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with that XSLT stylesheet Saxon 6.5.5 transforms

```
<a>
    <b id="1" ol="1" />
    <b id="2" ol="0" />
    <b id="3" ol="0" />
    <b id="4" ol="1" />
    <b id="5" ol="0" />
    <b id="6" ol="0" />
    <b id="7" ol="1" />
    <b id="8" ol="0" />
    <b id="9" ol="0" />
    <b id="10" ol="1" />
    <b id="11" ol="0" />
    <b id="12" ol="0" />
    <b id="13" ol="1" />
    <b id="14" ol="0" />
    <b id="15" ol="0" />
    <b id="16" ol="1" />
</a>
```

into

```
<tr>
   <p>1</p>
   <p>4</p>
   <p>7</p>
</tr>
<tr>
   <p>10</p>
   <p>13</p>
   <p>16</p>
</tr>
```

Comment: Any suggestions how to get what I want?

Comment: @ThatsEnough, I have edited my answer to provide an XSLT stylesheet creating the output sequences you want.

Answer (score 0):

$part selects elements with @ol=1, namely the elements 1,4,7,10,13,16.

$part[position() mod 3 = 1] selects the items in $part whose position within $part is 1, 4, 7, ...  That is, it selects the elements with ids 1 and 10.

You then apply templates to these, to output the groups of three elements starting with these two, which gives you the groups (1,2,3) and (10,11,12).

I think your mistake is probably in imagining that position() returns the position of an element in the tree, rather than the position of the element in the list you are filtering.

Comment: Give me please exaample how to get structure that I mentioned above.

Comment: I don't understand the problem well enough. You can either select all the items with @ol=1, or you can select every third item; with your sample data both give the same answer, but presumably that's not always the case.